# Android Background Service stops when screen is off

Tags: android, android-service, android-background

I am trying to scan beacons even when I quit my app using Service.
This is my code for the service.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter =bluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bleCheck(bluetoothAdapter);
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mScanCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand called");
        if (intent == null)
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        else{

        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy called");
    }
```

And these are the permissions i gave to app. I post all the permissions in case there might be problems.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

I used Wake_lock but it stops when the screen turns off. I cannot find the reason. And another question is that even though my phone OS is Android 9.0 the background service does not stop.
In the google document, I read that after Android Oreo, they strictly restrict app running on background but my app keeps on running.
Thanks for reading my question. Please help:)

Comment: I recommend you use foreground services
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Types-of-services

Comment: If I change to using foreground service, will it work?

Comment: sure, you'll need to create a notification to indicate that service is running in background and change a little bit your service's code